# org.apache.thrift~ java.net.SocketException:broken pipe in Cassandra keyspace

Tags: java, cassandra, broken-pipe

I need to create a keyspace using Cassandra-CLI, but when I execute the command

`create keyspace "name" with strategy_options={replication_factor:1};`

I get the message:

```
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
```

The first time, the second and next times I try to create it I get

```
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTtransportException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
```

My java -version is Java(TM) SE Runtime Enviroment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

Additional information:

When I run the command init.d/cassandra status I get the following message:

```
xss = -ea -javaagent:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms505M -Xmx505M -Xmn100 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss256k
[ ok ] Cassandra is running.
```